# Naming conventions for IDs, filegroup and files in SQL Server 2019 database

Tags: sql, sql-server, naming-conventions

In our project we are using [SQL Server name convention and T-SQL programming style](https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit/blob/master/SQL%20Server%20Name%20Convention%20and%20T-SQL%20Programming%20Style.md) and I am not sure how to name:

- Column with IDs. For now I am naming it with ID at the end of the column name. For example: `CustomerID`, `EmployeeID`
- File groups
- File names (`.ndf`)

Do you have any experience with naming conventions for these objects?

Comment: There are no standardized naming conventions for SQL Server, despite the hopes and dreams of the programmer on GitHub. There are only in-house decisions. Decide, then be consistent.

Comment: I've witnessed numerous initiatives and no successes.   It is my firm belief that current and solid documentation is far more valuable.